# Seg fault on same logic

Tags: c

In this `first_word` function, the `s[i]` is inside each loop

```
void    first_word(char *s)
{
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    while ((s[i] == 32 || (s[i] <= 8 && s[i] >= 11)) && s[i])
        i++;
    while (!(s[i] == 32 || (s[i] <= 8 && s[i] >= 11)) && s[i])
    {
        write(1, &s[i], 1);
        i++;
    }
}

int     main(int ac, char **argv)
{
    if (ac == 2)
        first_word(argv[1]);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
}
```

Here the `s[i]` is in an outer loop

```
void    first_word(char *s)
{
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    while (s[i])
    {
        while ((s[i] == 32 || (s[i] <= 8 && s[i] >= 11)))
            i++;
        while (!(s[i] == 32 || (s[i] <= 8 && s[i] >= 11)))
        {
            write(1, &s[i], 1);
            i++;
        }
    }
}

int     main(int ac, char **argv)
{
    if (ac == 2)
        first_word(argv[1]);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
}
```

Why do I have seg fault in the 2nd example, when logically it should work exactly the same?

Comment: What character does satisfy this condition (s[i] <= 8 && s[i] >= 11)?

Comment: Don't hard-code ASCII codes, use character literals. Use `' '` instead of `32`.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow its blank spaces, like tabs and such

Comment: @JoaoPereira How can something be less than 8 and also more than 11 at the same time?

Comment: @JoaoPereira Show at least one character that satisfy this condition.

Comment: There's a built-in function `isspace()` that matches all the whitespace characters.

Comment: @Barmar its a honest mistake hehe

Comment: Anyway, the reason is that the logic isn't the same. In the second version, you don't check for the null terminator until the second inner loop stops. It only stops when it gets to a space character.

Comment: @Barmar I was stubbornly thinking that inner loops would only work if outside loop condition was satisfied. Your explanation is perfect! Thank you very much Barmar! <3

Comment: @JoaoPereira That's a common beginner misunderstanding. It's not a condition that's implicitly added to each nested loop. Each loop is independent.

Comment: PSA: Don't split declaration with initialization for variables. This should be `int i = 0`, one line, no confusion, no possibility of using uninitialized values.

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step ⏯️ carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: @tadman I absolutely agree with you, but I study in a school called 42 that has some norms in how we code, and one of them is to not initialize values in the same line we create the variables.
Yes I usually use Python Tutor, but I wanted to get acquainted with stack overflow for the 1st time. It is awesome to talk with you experienced folk!

Comment: I mean you have to do what you have to do for a course no matter how esoteric or just plain ridiculous your teacher is. I'd *strongly* advise against carrying this habit forward into production code.

Comment: @tadman That is exactly what I plan to do :) I only have to follow these rules for the 1st half of the course. That is why I use while loops only. I am also forbidden on the use of for loops. They do it to build in us the necessary resilience to be a good programmer in the future. It is a free school that is fully financed by tech companies from around the world, so I trust I will have implemented the right habits by the end of it! And also with the help/by helping you extraordinary people here in stack overflow :)

Comment: I mean that is a taste of what it's like to work at a highly dysfunctional software company, the sort of which you'd never want to work at, but it is unnecessary. C is plenty hard enough on its own, and the compiler is a strict disciplinarian with the right warnings enabled!

Comment: Your last sentence hits close to the heart! Yes it might be pure masochism, but I went with the idea that if I can do this, then I can overcome any challenge in the programming world and own a powerful experience that can make companies trust in my abilities on the long term. And ofc in the end they will 100% offer a job depending on which area I want to specialize. Sure it might not be in the company of my dreams, but if it is a bad experience, at least I will know what I will want in my professional life. A man gotta start somewhere. I am also open minded. Do you know other ways to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, in both while loops, you check if `s[i]` isn't `\0` each iteration for both loops, which is correct.

In the second example, you only check if `s[i]` isn't equal to `\0` once - you check it in the outer loop condition, but you have to wait until the inner while loops have finished looping before you can check `s[i]` in the outer loop a second time. What this looks like is that the second inner while loop will continue looping through `s[i]` until you iterate past the null termination character (since `!(s[i] == 32 || (s[i] <= 8 && s[i] >= 11))` evaluates to `true` for `\0`). That causes the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I have seg fault ...?

`while (!(s[i] == 32 || (s[i] <= 8 && s[i] >= 11)))` is true for the *null character*, eventually leading to access beyond the string.

Do not iterate past the `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

The condition to test for whitespace characters is incorrect: `(s[i] == 32 || (s[i] <= 8 && s[i] >= 11))` is true for space only. You should instead check for byte values **in** the range 9..13 to handle `'\f'` and `'\r'`:

```
(s[i] == ' ' || (s[i] >= 8 && s[i] <= 13))
```

To match space, backspace (`8`), TAB (`'\t'`), newline (`'\n'`), vertical tab (`'\v'`), form feed (`'\f'`) and carriage return (`'\r'`).

Testing for the null character is only necessary in the second loop where you exclude whitespace **and** the null byte.  In the first loop, you increment `i` only if `s[i]` is one of the whitespace characters, and with the corrected expression, `'\0'` does not match the test.

Furthermore, you should not wrap the inner loops inside a third loop: as coded, the function will print all non whitespace characters in the string, not what is expected from a function named `first_word`.

Here is a modified version using the macros from `<ctype.h>`:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void first_word(const char *s)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (isspace((unsigned char)s[i]))
        i++;
    while (s[i] && !isspace((unsigned char)s[i])) {
        write(1, &s[i], 1);
        i++;
    }
}

int main(int ac, char **argv)
{
    if (ac == 2)
        first_word(argv[1]);
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    return 0;
}
```

And for illustration, here is an alternative using standard yet often overlooked functions from `<string.h>`:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void first_word(const char *s) {
    s += strspn(s, " \010\t\n\v\n\r");
    write(1, s, strcspn(s, " \010\t\n\v\n\r"));
}

int main(int ac, char **argv)
{
    if (ac == 2) {
        first_word(argv[1]);
    }
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    return 0;
}
```